# How to save the contents of a PHP webpage to an XML file?

Tags: php, xml

I currently have code that generates XML code for all of the contacts within my Oracle array. I have tried to use the built in XML methods within PHP, but it did not give me the amount of control I need to get the right schema. Thus far, I have been running the PHP file which echoes all the XML code to a webpage and then selecting all within the page, pasting it to a blank Notepad file and saving it as XML. This works perfectly for now, but essentially I would like to be able to run the PHP file and end up with a saved XML file with a dynamic naming convention (writing_request_yyyymmddtttt.xml). Is there any way to easily accomplish this to make the process more automated? Here is a snippet of the code:

```
echo    htmlspecialchars('<contact contactID="'.$row["UNIQUE ID"].'" action="AddOrModify">')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="LastName">'.$row["LAST NAME"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="FirstName">'.$row["FIRST NAME"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="MiddleName">'.$row["MIDDLE INITIAL"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="Country">'.$row["COUNTRY"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="Code">'.$row["CODE"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 1"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 1"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 2"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 2"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 3"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 3"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 4"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 4"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 5"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 5"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 6"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 6"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 7"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 7"].'</contactField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactField name="CustomField" customName="'.$row["CUSTOM LABEL 8"].'">'.$row["CUSTOM VALUE 8"].'</contactField>')."<br><br>".


    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointList>')."<br>".

    htmlspecialchars('<contactPoint type="Voice">')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["PHONE LABEL 1"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="CountryCode">'.$row["PHONE 1 COUNTRY CODE"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Number">'.$row["PHONE 1"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Extension">'.$row["PHONE EXTENSION 1"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('</contactPoint>')."<br><br>".

    htmlspecialchars('<contactPoint type="Voice">')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["PHONE 2 LABEL"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="CountryCode">'.$row["PHONE 2 COUNTRY CODE"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Number">'.$row["PHONE 2"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Extension">'.$row["PHONE EXTENSION 2"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('</contactPoint>')."<br><br>".

    htmlspecialchars('<contactPoint type="Email">')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Label">'.$row["EMAIL LABEL 1"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('<contactPointField name="Address">'.$row["EMAIL 1"].'</contactPointField>')."<br>".
    htmlspecialchars('</contactPoint>')."<br><br>".
    htmlspecialchars('</contactPointList>')."<br><br>".
    htmlspecialchars('</contact>')."<br><br>";
```

This is being run within the oci_fetch_array loop that also validates all the data. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: *"I have tried to use the built in XML methods within PHP, but it did not give me the amount of control I need to get the right schema"* What are the problems you encountered? Perhaps those can be solved? That seems like a much better route to me than your current code .

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `echo`, save the content a variable and then create a new file with `fopen()` and write to it with `fwrite()`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

I think you should not use `<br>` in your code, it seems like you want to do a line break, use `"\n"` instead or `"\r\n"` on Windows, `PHP_EOL` is another option as well.

Comment: Thank you, using the fwrite was an easy solution!